# How to weekly aggregate data in sql and include skipped weeks too

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working in SQL Server 2008. I am writing a stored procedure which aggregates data on a weekly basis.

Code for aggregation is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ups_URLBatchStats] 
   (@startDate datetime, @endDate datetime,@source varchar(8))
AS BEGIN
    SELECT 
       DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, ScheduleDate), 6) AS [Week Commencing], 
       SUM(Unresolved) AS Unresolved,
       SUM(Resolved) AS Resolved,
       SUM(TurkSpend) AS TurkSpend
    FROM 
       dbo.V_URLBatchStats 
    WHERE
       ScheduleDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate 
       AND Source = ISNULL(@source, Source)
    GROUP BY
       DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, ScheduleDate), 6)
    ORDER BY 
       DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, ScheduleDate), 6)
END
```

Show it gives me correct result, but if there are no data for any week I have to show it with values of '0' in the columns.

So how can I handled these skipped weekly rows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are currently selecting the wrong week, I tried to fix this:

```
SELECT dateadd(wk, number, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @startdate)-1, 6)) AS [Week Commencing], 
coalesce(SUM(Unresolved), 0) AS Unresolved,
coalesce(sum(Resolved), 0)as Resolved,
coalesce(sum(TurkSpend), 0) as TurkSpend
FROM dbo.V_URLBatchStats 
right join
master..spt_values 
on ScheduleDate between @startDate and @endDate and Source=ISNULL(@source,Source)
where type = 'P' and dateadd(wk, number, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @startdate)-1, 6)) <= @enddate
GROUP BY dateadd(wk, number, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @startdate)-1, 6))
ORDER BY dateadd(wk, number, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @startdate)-1, 6))
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, this is good but there is one problem, it actually generating wrong result but good thing is that it also include weeks whose records not in database.

Comment: @PavanTiwari my version find the beginning of the week. Test this: SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, '2011-01-01')-1, 6) It finds the first monday in the week. So i am assuming it is the script you are currently using that is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can `RIGHT JOIN` your week column with sysobjects with a row number generated:

```
SELECT o.Num AS [Week Commencing], SUM(Unresolved) AS Unresolved,sum(Resolved)as Resolved,sum(TurkSpend) as TurkSpend 
FROM dbo.V_URLBatchStats s
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) as [Num] FROM sysobjects) o 
    on DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, ScheduleDate), 6) = o.Num
WHERE ScheduleDate between @startDate and @endDate 
AND Source=ISNULL(@source,Source)
GROUP BY DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, ScheduleDate), 6), o.Num
ORDER BY 1
```

Note this is written from memory and untested, but the principle should work.

Comment: Thannks for your response ,but could u explane what is object_id in above query.

Comment: to fill in the blanks, you need something to generate the numbers in the middle.  The sysobjects tables has lots of data in it, so by using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function you can generate numbers to join on to.

Comment: ok
But it i am getting an error 
Invalid column name 'object_id'.

Comment: ah ok, it may just be `objectid`